# Bump functions and extensions of smooth maps

Tags: differential-geometry

I have two statements that are seemingly similar, but turns out that only one of them is true.

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $U$ an open subset of $M$. Let $f: U \to \Bbb R$ be a smooth map, then there exists an extension $\widetilde{f}$ of $f$ with $\widetilde{f}\vert_U = f$.

> Suppose $f$ is a smooth function defined on a neighborhood $U$ of a point $p$ in a manifold $M$. Then there is a smooth function $\widetilde{f}$ on $M$ that agrees with $f$ in some possibly smaller neighborhood of $p$.

Now the latter one is true which can be proved by using bump functions, but the former seems not to be true. Could someone help me understand what is the biggest distinction between these two statements? I guess it has something to do with the local nature of the second one by focusing on a singular point $p$ and a possibly smaller neighborhood of it?

Comment: Even when $M=\mathbb R $ and when smoothness is replaced with continuity, this distinction exists. Just notice that $1/x$ on $(0,\infty)$ cannot be extended to larger interval continuously. The point is that to be able to extend a function on V continuously, the limit of the function on the boundary of V must exist. The second statement ensures this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first assertion is false because a smooth function on $U \subset M$ can have a pathological behaviour near the boundary of $U$.
For instance, if $M = \Bbb R$, $U = (0,+\infty)$ and $f(t) = \ln t$ on $U$, then $f$ cannot be extended on $\Bbb R$ as a smooth function (even as a continuous function) due to the fact that $f$ explodes at $0$.
It is not the only possible pathological behaviour: replace $f$ by $\sin\frac{1}{t}$ for instance, which is bounded but not extendible at $0$.

This problem does not occur if one is looking for an extension on some smaller subset $\tilde{U}\subset U$ that is away enough from the boundary of $U$ (for instance if $\tilde{U}$ is relatively compact in $U$).
This prevents $f|_{\tilde{U}}$ to have a pathological behaviour in a neighbourhood of the boundary of $\tilde{U}$.